# App.yaml missing when downloading source

Tags: google-app-engine

Just tried downloading source for one of my old apps using SDK 1.7.4.437 (on a Mac) and the source downloaded did not contain app.yaml file.

Used the following command: `appcfg.py download_app -A <application_id> -V <version> <folder>`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.yaml is not uploaded when you deploy your project

**UPDATE**

The Downloaded Source Code Is Missing The .yaml Files : http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4337

But finding this issue again, I also found this entry. See the list of downloaded files.
http://forums.udacity.com/questions/6006963/downloading-your-source-from-google-app-engine